# Steps to change web application host header

Tags: 2013, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I created a new web application with a host header in a SharePoint farm and later we decided to change the name of web application with different host header name.

In order to not get any issues what are the recommended steps to change the web application name?

I created web application: `http://sharepoint`
I want to change to: `http://intranetdev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through powershell:

```
$WebApp = SPWebApplication | where {$_.Name -match "OldWebAppName"}
$WebApp.Name ="NewWebAppName"
$WebApp.Update()
# This bit is just to verify it updated correctly
Get-SPWebApplication | where {$_.Name -match "NewWebAppName"}
```

This script will change only the name of the web application , however to change the **url** of the web application we need to go with **Alternate Access Mappings** and **IIS Bindings** .

To Rename SharePoint 2013 web application URL, lets update the AAM entries first. Go to: **Central Administration >> System Settings >> Configure alternate access mappings under Farm Management**. Pick your web application and give a new URL to it.

[image]

Update HOST Name in **IIS Bindings** to rename SharePoint Web application URL:
Next step is to update IIS bindings. Go to **IIS (Start > Run > InetMgr)**, Select your target web application, Click on **"Bindings"** on right pane.

[image]

Comment: Great Answer @Esaki, ♥

Answer (score 0):

I tested the answer to this question with the case where I stop and start the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service in Central Admin". See [this link](https://blog.russmax.com/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010/) I can confirm that my old URL will come back in IIS after that. I tested this on SharePoint 2013. So removing the site from IIS and extending again will do the job.