# Changing webapplication host header

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, web-application-zones

Can I change my host header for my webapplication simply by adding a new binding in IIS, and changing the AAM for the default zone to the new URL?

According to [this link](https://blog.russmax.com/how-to-properly-change-the-host-header-url-of-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010/) I have to do more than that.
According to [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202616/steps-to-change-web-application-host-header)changing binding and AAM should be sufficient

Comment: Have a look at this answer it should do the trick for you:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202616/steps-to-change-web-application-host-header

Comment: This works but when you stop and start the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service in Central Admin" the original URL will get backl into IIS. So the URL is not changed in the configuration database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do more work as Russ mentioned in his blog. he very well explained the reason, "making any change to Web Application settings without proper way, will not update the configuration database". So when we have an issue with SharePoint farm, sharepoint will knew old host header url.

Extending and un-extending the web application is way to go with it, it is little pain in start but more reliable. when you do this, make sure do it in off hours, it will cause the outage.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I change the URL for the default zone in my test env it also gets changed automatically in my content source in my search service application.

Comment: I tested the case where I stop and start the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service in Central Admin". I can confirm that my old URL will come back in IIS after that