# Steps to change web application host header (duplicated question) - share point designer 2013 doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-designer, credentials, connection

on [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202616/steps-to-change-web-application-host-header/280860#280860) help how to change web application host name. this is ok.
but after change, why i can't login to web application with share point designer. when open share point designer and type new web application address name. share point designer ask me username & password but i am system account user and after type my credential user name & password, share point designer show again login window. please help me. 
[image]
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple reasons SharePoint users will be asked to enter the credentials multiple times, so you can check the following :

- Implement Kerberos authentication in your SharePoint server.
- Connect all SharePoint servers those are part of SharePoint farm
  under a single common domain and make sure all users available in the
  single active directory domain same as SharePoint server domain.
- Make sure that there is no network devices, like proxy servers or
  firewalls which unveils the authentication information from the
  network communications between your local laptop/desktop and the
  SharePoint servers.
- If you have enabled Anonymous authentication then we need to make
  sure that Require Use Remote Interfaces permission is Disabled
  . Select your web application from Central admin -> Click on
  Authentication Providers -> Click on the Default zone. Then we will
  get the below page. Here if we see enable anonymous access
  is checked then ensure that Require Use Remote Interfaces permission
  is unchecked
- Make sure that SharePoint Web Services IIS website authentication
  configuration is correct means need to ensure the SharePoint Web
  Services IIS website is having same authentication as your web
  application where you are facing problem. To verify this follow this
  navigation – Go to IIS server and select the “SharePoint Web
  Services” web application and compare the below authentication with
  your SharePoint authentication.
- If you have DNS Proxy enabled, it is recommended that disable the DNS
  proxy and test your web application.

Reference Article:

[Why multiple times SharePoint users are asked to enter the credentials?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-troubleshooting/why-multiple-times-sharepoint-users-are-asked-to-enter-the-credentials/amp/)

Answer (score 0):

their could be couple of issues

- if you enabled the kerberos authentication then make sure that SPN are properly created for new host name.
- Add the new host name in the trusted sites list of browser
- [clear the SharePoint designer cache.](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-cache-2010-2013/)

Alos check this, may help. http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/02/sharepoint-keeps-prompting-for-credentials/